# Change property of RLMObject without commiting

Tags: ios, realm

I'm using Realm because it's useful and sexy.

I'm trying to handle user settings in a view controller, by changing the User properties as the field values change.

Since my `User` is a subclass of `RLMObject`, I must do the usual

```
    [self.defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
    user.name = textfield.text;
    [self.defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];
```

around each user property set.

But this way Realm writes every changes, and if I tap "cancel", the previous values will be overwrited.

What's the better way to discard my changes?

EDIT:

I can imagine a solution by calling in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
```

in `didPressOk`

```
[self.defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];
```

in `didPressCancel`

```
[self.defaultRealm cancelWriteTransaction];
```

but I don't feel that's the right solution, and i'm afraid it'll cause deadlocks...

Comment: Realm user here too :)     How about you only change your user object and update all his fields in the didPressOk function?

Comment: If I do `user.name = textfield.text;` without the surrounding begin/commit, Realm crashes while saying `Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction`. Another solution would be to save the form changes in a dictionary and save the dic in the user on the `didPressOk`, but I wonder if there is an easier solution.

Comment: I didn't mean not to use the begin/ commit sequence. I meant to call begin, change all the user properties, and then commit at the end.

Comment: Ah ok. That's I've written in my edits. I didn't try and I'm not sure if it's a good solution. I would like to hear some Realm developer feedback before implementing this option for production.

Comment: Where do you set this now `[self.defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
    user.name = textfield.text;
    [self.defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];`, what function?

Comment: for example, on `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`, it's called while the user fill the form.

Comment: So, every time the user finish editing a field you were changing the user object property, based on which textField was edited. My sugestion was to do it just once in didPressOk function. Have begin transaction, then set all the properties of the user object, with their coresponding textFields, and then commit at the end.

Comment: But if there's another thread trying to write during the time I lock the defaultRealm, I wonder if it would wait that long, that's why I'm asking the question to know if it's a good practice :) Are you telling me "yes that's a good practice ?". Did you try this solution ?

Comment: The time the default Realm is locked, in your case when you change one property, and my case when I change a few properties, is almost 0, and almost no difference at all. Yes, that how I use it in my app. I have a view where the user can change some things, and at the end I set all the properties on the object at once.

Comment: Aaah, ok I misunderstood your solution. For some reason, I don't have directAccess to my textfields in didPressOk.

Comment: Ok. Another solution. Create a new user object set it to have the same properties as your current user object. Then modify it in the textFiled delegate methods as you need, and at the end do an `createOrUpdateInRealm:`.

Comment: Hum... this solution seems better, indeed. I will try it soon, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to add a `- (void)save;` method to your class.

```
- (void)save
{
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm addOrUpdateObject:self];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

Don't begin/commit changes every time you change a property. (That's very inefficient in any case). Instead, make the changes as normal, then call `save` when the user is done. If you don't call save, the changes won't persist.

Also, your intuition is right: you shouldn't call `[self.defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction]` on `viewDidLoad`; the app will crash if you happen to open a transaction anywhere else in the app while the view controller is open.

If you have already persisted this particular object, make a copy of it first, so you can change the properties without raising an exception.

Comment: unfortunately, I switched to Core Data on this project and did not try Realm again on another, so I can't test your proposition. But It seems to be a good one, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Pteofil is correct, you can create a standalone RLMObject and then decide whether you want to add that to the Realm using `createOrUpdateInRealm:`, you can read more about it here http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/latest/#updating-objects

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing a "clone" method which would copy the original object and then use the cloned one to receive the modified values from the user input.

Since the original object and the cloned object will share the same "primary key" if you want to save call the realm method realm.add(clonedobject, update: true) to commit your changes or just don't do anything if you want to discard the changes since the original object was not modified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but last year I chose to drop the realm solution because it was still in dev and my project was a production which needed a stable db. If someone find an accepted answer among these one, please let me know by posting a comment, so I can accept it.